# Script to Transfer Column Values to 1 of 4 Columns Based on Empty Columns

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out a script to automate the transfer of data from a column on one sheet, to one of four columns on another sheet. The data being transferred is an order that has been placed, so the data needs to stay in the column its transferred to until it is received. So basically the script needs to find the next blank column and transfer the data there.

For reference, the sheet is HERE:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DxafMMZL7Nc2M4A41Dzssf9dgrzYZgsX1qKgtfhLMlM/edit?usp=sharing. The data that will be transferred is Ordering!P5:P, and will be transferred from there to Pending TOs, either E6:E, F6:F, G6:G or H6:H, based on whether the previous column already has values.

I wrote the following script, but it only worked on the initial test, and fails to detect empty columns F:H. After clearing column E, I could not repeat the initial success.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
function PasteTOTEST() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const response = ui.alert('Table is full', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  var copyFrom = ss.getRange('Ordering!P5:P');
  var copyTo = ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Pending TOs'));
  var toColumnA = copyTo.getRange('E6:E').activate();
  var toColumnB = copyTo.getRange('F6:F').activate();
  var toColumnC = copyTo.getRange('G6:G').activate();
  var toColumnD = copyTo.getRange('H6:H').activate();
  
  if(ISBLANK(toColumnA)) {
    toColumnA;
    copyFrom.copyTo(ss.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  }
  else if(ISBLANK(toColumnB)) {
    toColumnB;
    copyFrom.copyTo(ss.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  }
  else if(ISBLANK(toColumnC)) {
    toColumnC;
    copyFrom.copyTo(ss.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  }
  else if(ISBLANK(toColumnD)) {
    toColumnD;
    copyFrom.copyTo(ss.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a function named `ISBLANK`? See [mcve]. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for free resources and more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This function will paste the data in the first available column in ranges E6:E, F6:F, G6:G or H6:H

```
function PasteTOTEST() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const fsh = ss.getSheetByName('Ordering');
  const tsh = ss.getSheetByName('Pending TOs');
  let frg = fsh.getRange(5, 16, getColHite(16, fsh, ss) - 4, 1);
  let ar = availableRanges();
  if(ar && ar.length) {
    trg = tsh.getRange(6, ar[0]);
    frg.copyTo(trg, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  } else {
    ui.alert('Table is full', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  }
}

function getColHite(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rcA = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow()) { rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse(); }
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
}

function clearAllRanges() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Pending TOs');
  [...Array.from(Array(4).keys(), x => x + 5)].forEach(n => {
    let h = getColHite(n, sh, ss)
    if(h>4)sh.getRange(5, n, h - 4, 1).clearContent()
  });
}

function availableRanges() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Pending TOs');
  let r = [...Array.from(Array(4).keys(), x => x + 5)].reduce((a,v,arr) => {
     let h = getColHite(v, sh, ss);
     if(h < 6) a.r.push(v);
     return a;
  },{r:[],availableRanges:function(){return this.r;}}).availableRanges();
  //Logger.log(r);
  return r;
}
```

Demo:

[image]

In case you are wondering what this does:

```
[...Array.from(Array(4).keys(), x => x + 5)]
```

It just feeds the four column numbers into the reduce loop current value

Comment: Hi Cooper, this worked wonderfully. Thank you! I very much appreciate it.